# How can I import a local postgres file into my Heroku postgres database?

Tags: django, database, postgresql, heroku, database-migration

My django application is working perfectly fetching and inserting data into local postgres database. Now i have data in my local postgres database. When i deployed my app on heroku and run migrate command in heroku then it create the tables. But the tables are empty.

**I just want to know that Did i have to insert all my data again in heroku postgres database or there is any way to migrate/export the local postgres database with data to heroku postgres database?**

Comment: Have you ever tried [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export#import)?

Comment: I read that documentation, but in that they had written that we need to upload it somewhere with an HTTP-accessible URL(they had used aws s3). But can we do not do directly?

Comment: If the docs do not say so, I don't believe there are stable ways that you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `django-admin dumpdata` and `django-admin loaddata` commands
run the first command in your local machine and upload the generated file to your server and run the `loaddata` command on your server to restore your data
further reading [example](https://coderwall.com/p/mvsoyg/django-dumpdata-and-loaddata) [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/django-admin/#dumpdata)

Comment: When i run this command: python manage.py dumpdata > db.json
File is created, but when i run this command: heroku run python manage.py loaddata db.json
I got this error:
System check identified some issues:

WARNINGS:
?: (urls.W005) URL namespace 'admin' isn't unique. You may not be able to reverse all URLs in this namespace
CommandError: No fixture named 'db' found.

Comment: it can't find your db.json file in your server check it's location and path is correct

Comment: `django.core.serializers.base.DeserializationError: Problem installing fixture '/app/data.json'`